# CoreData & sqlite

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data, ios7

I have an App using a sql base. I created this base with `1 Entity`, `10 Attributes` at the begining. 
So, now I have to add new attributes. (4 more), so I did the versioning, model ... update.

Then, I changed my App in order to access to my new fields values. But, what I don't understand, is how my App can access to my new field in the updated sqlite data base.

Certainly doing something wrong but honestly don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're using SQLite or not makes absolutely no difference here. Similarly, if lightweight migration is working (i.e. the store is being opened successfully) then there's really little more to say about that.

Assuming you're using `NSManagedObject` subclasses then what you've probably not realised is that merely updating your model doesn't update the classes you generated for it. So you need to do that again. It'll add the new properties to the relevant classes.

You could write a quick test using key-value coding to demonstrate that the fields are there — e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [object valueForKey:@"newProperty"]);
```

... but you should probably stick to generating new class definitions and using the runtime-synthesised getters and setters that flow from there, as it'll allow the compiler better to verify what you're typing and will lead to more efficient code at runtime.

Comment: Right, I'm using MSManagedObject, but, how to regenerate it. Tried to redo the light migration, .... but, still the same. valueKey is returning nil.

Comment: The subclasses are generated from the scheme and are part of the compile. The migration will occur once only, at runtime.

Comment: Understood, but, issue after the light migration by adding attributes, how to establih the link with my sql base. Or how to access to the new sql field ? (is an automatic creation or do I have to create manually ? )

Comment: Ok, so, I found the solution. So let me explain it easely. What's not clearly mentionned, is that, the migration work perfectly but, how to check the database ? Once executed, the right database is stored in the simulator folder. Then I took this sql base and waooouuu modified. Then, used this based in order to fill manually the data. !!!!!